# flex shrink 0 causes scrollbar to disappear and it ignores overflow auto in fire fox edge and ie but not in chrome why

Tags: css, flexbox

This code is designed to show the numbers in column reverse order from 1 to 4 so I suddenly realize I did not like how display flex was setting the .numbers height and it was ignoring my height in 200px in the numbers class name so I added

flex-shrink: 0;

and it prevented display flex from setting it's own height and it suddenly showed the .numbers original height so I was happy :)

so this is how it looks in Chrome

[image]

but sadly flex-shrink: 0 gave strange results in Edge, IE and Fire fox I notice in those browsers it removed the scrollbar and it ignored the overflow-y: auto; mentioned in the #numbers-container.
[image]

How can I get it to work like the chrome browser in those other browsers that it did not work in ? :(

**Code**

```css
#container{
  background-color: #d6b68d;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

#numbers-container{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.numbers{
  background-color: forestgreen;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.numbers h1{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='numbers-container'>
    
    <div class='numbers'>
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div><!--</numbers>-->
 
    <div class='numbers'>
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div><!--</numbers>-->

    <div class='numbers'>
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div><!--</numbers>-->

    <div class='numbers'>
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div><!--</numbers>-->
    
  </div><!--</numbers-container>-->
</div><!--</container>-->
```

Comment: different browsers look at `flex` very differently. See known issues here. https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: If you want cross-browsers workaround - the community made some here : https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Answer (score 0):

You could move the scrolling onto it's own container:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

#container {
  background-color: #d6b68d;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#numbers-container {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.numbers {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.numbers h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll">
    <div id="numbers-container">

      <div class="numbers">
        <h1>1</h1>
      </div>
      <!--</numbers>-->

      <div class="numbers">
        <h1>2</h1>
      </div>
      <!--</numbers>-->

      <div class="numbers">
        <h1>3</h1>
      </div>
      <!--</numbers>-->

      <div class="numbers">
        <h1>4</h1>
      </div>
      <!--</numbers>-->

    </div>
    <!--</numbers-container>-->
  </div>
  <!--</scroll-container>-->
</div>
<!--</container>-->
```

However, if you want to start your scroll from the bottom, you would probably need to use js